# Socket connection an unconnected

Tags: c++, sockets

I do not know if I can do what I want to do. Basically what I want to do is to know when I have the ethernet connetion and when I do not have it. I have this code, it is basically a socket to an IP:

```
void* RecvTP(void*)
{
    struct sockaddr_in remoteSocketInfo;
    struct hostent *hPtr;
    int socketHandle;
    const char *remoteHost="192.168.1.70";
    int portNumber = 65000;
    char *pcIpAddress;
    unsigned short shPort;

    bzero(&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in));  // Clear structure memory

    // Get system information

    if((hPtr = gethostbyname(remoteHost)) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "System DNS name resolution not configured properly." << endl;
        cerr << "Error number: " << ECONNREFUSED << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // create socket

    if((socketHandle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {

       cout<<"error1"<<endl;
       close(socketHandle);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Load system information into socket data structures

    memcpy((char *)&remoteSocketInfo.sin_addr, hPtr->h_addr, hPtr->h_length);
    remoteSocketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remoteSocketInfo.sin_port = htons((u_short)portNumber);      // Set port number



    int rc = 0;  // Actual number of bytes read by function read()
    char buf[4];


  while(1){

      if(connect(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
 {
      cout<<"error2"<<endl;
    //  close(socketHandle);
     // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 if(connect(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) >= 0)
 {
     cout<<"NO error"<<endl;
    // close(socketHandle);
         // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

   rc = recv(socketHandle, buf, 4, 0);

/*   if ( rc == 0 || rc == -1)
   {
       cerr << "ERROR! Socket closed" << endl;
   }

   else if (rc == -1)
   {
       cerr << "ERROR! Socket error" << endl;
       close(socketHandle);
   }*/

    if(buf[2]=='3')
        recievePhoneState=0x01;
    else
       if(buf[2]=='0')
        recievePhoneState=0x02;

}
```

}

What I want to know is If I can have control that when I have connection, and when I don't.
I am trying to do with the function connect, but it is not works, there is some socket funcion or something in which I can to know if I have connection and when I don't?

Someone have some Idea?

Comment: Are you on Windows? On Windows you must initialize WinSock before using socket functions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The only reliable way to detect abnormal disconnections is to implement application-level ping/heartbeat.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your answers, I am working in linux, ubuntu. Where can I see an example of ping/heartbeat?